# Validate form only if one or more field contains a number, Angular.JS

Tags: angularjs, forms, validation, input, numbers

I want to validate an order form with Angular.JS.

The form dynamically adds input fields depending on how many products there are.

The dynamically added input fields are used to determine how many products the user wants to purchase.

I want the form to validate if either one of the fields has a value of minimum 1 (the user has to choose at least one product in order to send the form).

**The issue I am having is that I cannot work out how the conditional validation "if one field has a value greater than 0 the form is valid".**

If I put in `min='1'` as an attribute for the input field, both field needs to have a value of 1 in order for the form to work.

If I have a `placeholder="0"` the input fields has a value and therefore will validate the form as long as the other fields are valid.

My idea which I do not know how to implement (or if it's smart) is to check the products total sum is greater than 0.

Obviously I am a newbie and use a lot of resources online to implement functionality I want to have.

HTML

```
<form id="orderForm" name="orderForm" role="form" ng-submit="submitForm(orderForm.$valid)" class="orderForm" ng-controller="formController as formCtrl" novalidate>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Produkt</th>
                <th scope="col">Antal</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-right">Pris</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="product in formCtrl.products">
                <td>
                    <img ng-src="{{product.images.thumb}}" alt="{{product.name}}">
                    <h6 class="d-inline-block">{{product.name}} <small class="d-block">{{product.description}}</small></h6>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="product.quantity" name="{{'quantity' + product.productId}}" min="0" max="99" required>

                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    {{product.price | currency : "SEK"}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="text-right">
                    <h5 class="d-inline-block">Totalt: <em ng-bind="sumCalc(product.price) | currency : 'SEK'"></em></h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input name="email" ng-model="formCtrl.email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.email.$invalid && !orderForm.email.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i en korrekt email
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputFirstName">Förnamn</label>
            <input name="firstname" ng-model="formCtrl.fName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="Förnamn" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.fName.$invalid && !orderForm.fName.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i ditt förnamn
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputLastName">Efternamn</label>
            <input name="lastname" ng-model="formCtrl.lName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Efternamn" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.lName.$invalid && !orderForm.lName.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i ditt efternamn
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputStreet">Gatuadress</label>
            <input name="street" ng-model="formCtrl.street" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputStreet" placeholder="Gatuadress" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.street.$invalid && !orderForm.street.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i din gatuaddress
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputZip">Postnr</label>
            <input name="zip" ng-model="formCtrl.zip" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" placeholder="Postnummer" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.zip.$invalid && !orderForm.zip.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i ditt postnummer
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputTown">Stad</label>
            <input name="town" ng-model="formCtrl.town" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTown" placeholder="Stad" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.town.$invalid && !orderForm.town.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i din stad
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div> orderForm is {{orderForm.$valid}}</div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="inputSubmitButton" ng-disabled="orderForm.$invalid && inputQuantity.">Skicka</button>

    </div>
</form>
```

controllers.js

```
var app = angular.module('controllers', []);
app.controller('formController', function($scope) {

    this.products = product;
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {
            alert('our form is amazing');
        }

    };

    $scope.sumCalc = function() {
        var sum = 0;
        angular.forEach(product, function(product, index) {
            sum += parseInt(product.quantity, 10) * product.price;

        });
        return sum;
        //totalPrice = sum;
    };
});

var product = [{
        name: 'asd',
        productId: 01,
        price: 100,
        description: 'asd',
        specification: "asd",
        images: {
            full: 'asd',
            thumb: 'asd'
        },
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        name: "asd",
        productId: 02,
        price: 100,
        description: "asd",
        specification: "asd",
        images: {
            full: 'asd',
            thumb: 'asd'
        },
        quantity: 0
    }
];
var app = angular.module('controllers', []);
app.controller('formController', function($scope) {

    this.products = product;
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
        // check to make sure the form is completely valid
        if (isValid) {
            alert('our form is amazing');
        }

    };

    $scope.sumCalc = function() {
        var sum = 0;
        angular.forEach(product, function(product, index) {
            sum += parseInt(product.quantity, 10) * product.price;

        });
        return sum;
        //totalPrice = sum;
    };
});

var product = [{
        name: 'asd',
        productId: 01,
        price: 100,
        description: 'asd',
        specification: "asd",
        images: {
            full: 'asd',
            thumb: 'asd'
        },
        quantity: 0
    },
    {
        name: "asd",
        productId: 02,
        price: 100,
        description: "asd",
        specification: "asd",
        images: {
            full: 'asd',
            thumb: 'asd'
        },
        quantity: 0
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit your HTML as following:

```
<form id="orderForm" name="orderForm" role="form" ng-submit="submitForm(orderForm.$valid)" class="orderForm" ng-controller="formController as formCtrl" novalidate>

    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Produkt</th>
                <th scope="col">Antal</th>
                <th scope="col" class="text-right">Pris</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="product in formCtrl.products">
                <td>
                    <img ng-src="{{product.images.thumb}}" alt="{{product.name}}">
                    <h6 class="d-inline-block">{{product.name}} <small class="d-block">{{product.description}}</small></h6>
                </td>
                <td>

                    <input type="number" class="form-control" ng-model="product.quantity" name="{{'quantity' + product.productId}}" min="0" max="99" required>

                </td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    {{product.price | currency : "SEK"}}
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3" class="text-right">
                    <h5 class="d-inline-block">Totalt: <em ng-bind="sumCalc(product.price) | currency : 'SEK'"></em></h5>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
            <input name="email" ng-model="formCtrl.email" type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.email.$invalid && !orderForm.email.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i en korrekt email
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputFirstName">Förnamn</label>
            <input name="firstname" ng-model="formCtrl.fName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputFirstName" placeholder="Förnamn" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.fName.$invalid && !orderForm.fName.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i ditt förnamn
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputLastName">Efternamn</label>
            <input name="lastname" ng-model="formCtrl.lName" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputLastName" placeholder="Efternamn" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.lName.$invalid && !orderForm.lName.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i ditt efternamn
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputStreet">Gatuadress</label>
            <input name="street" ng-model="formCtrl.street" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputStreet" placeholder="Gatuadress" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.street.$invalid && !orderForm.street.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i din gatuaddress
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputZip">Postnr</label>
            <input name="zip" ng-model="formCtrl.zip" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputZip" placeholder="Postnummer" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.zip.$invalid && !orderForm.zip.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i ditt postnummer
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="inputTown">Stad</label>
            <input name="town" ng-model="formCtrl.town" type="text" class="form-control" id="inputTown" placeholder="Stad" required>
            <div ng-show="orderForm.town.$invalid && !orderForm.town.$pristine" class="invalid-feedback">
                Vänligen fyll i din stad
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div> orderForm is {{orderForm.$valid}}</div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="inputSubmitButton" ng-disabled="orderForm.$invalid || !checkProductSelected()">Skicka</button> <!--Pay attention to the 'ng-disabled' binding-->

    </div>
</form>
```

and modify your Javascript to look like this:

```
app.controller('formController', function($scope) {

    this.products = product;
    $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if (isValid) {
      alert('our form is amazing');
    }

    };

    $scope.sumCalc = function() {
    var sum = 0;
    angular.forEach(product, function(product, index) {
      sum += parseInt(product.quantity, 10) * product.price;

    });
    return sum;
    //totalPrice = sum;
    };


    //***The following function is added to your original code***
    $scope.checkProductSelected = function() {

        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(product, function(product, index) {

            sum += parseInt(product.quantity, 10) * product.price;
        });

        return sum > 0;
    }
});
```

Look for the comments in the code to see what has been added or edited. (On HTML it's after your submit button)